# GWT ScrollPanel in SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, celllist, layoutpanels

I have a scrollPanel in SplitLayoutPanel which I want to fill with log messages as user progresses in doing some of the activities the application is supposed to do. It just an attempt to provide the user the logger console on UI page to see whats going on on the server. I have used CellList to fill in the scrollbar with the log messages which I keep polling every few seconds. The problem is after certain amount of log messages coming on scrollPanel, it just stops printing any more. I gave Max buffer size and keep removing the old items from the cellList when it reaches the Max limit just to avoid going out of memory. And I know it works as expected. But no idea why it stops.
Any thoughts on it?

Comment: would it be possible for you to provide code ?

Comment: For some random reason the cellList refresh after the timed async call was not working properly. Fixed the refresh method and it went away. Sorry for so late updates on it. I totally forgot to add comment here after my fix.

Comment: No issues. Glad that it worked well.